# Map directed edge attribute to scale_edge_color_gradient aes in ggraph

Tags: r, ggplot2, network-programming, ggraph, tidygraph

I'm learning to use **tidygraph** and **ggraph** to plot social network data. I like it so far, but I can't figure out how to use color gradients to indicate edge direction while also mapping the color (that the gradient is based on) to an edge attribute.

*Example data*

```
require(tidygraph)
require(ggraph)

edges_df <- tibble(from = c("A","A","B","C","C","D"),
                   to = c("C","B","D","B","D","A"),
                   edgewidth = c(1,3,3,2,4,1),
                   edgegradient = factor(c("red","blue","red","blue","blue","red"))) 
# I realize edge gradient could be any attribute, not necessarily the names of the desired colors.

nodes_df <- tibble(node_id = c("A","B","C","D"))

my_graph <- tbl_graph(directed = TRUE, nodes = nodes_df, edges = edges_df)

ggraph(my_graph %>%
         activate(edges), layout = "linear", circular = TRUE) +
  geom_edge_arc(aes(width = edgewidth, color = stat(..index..))) +
  geom_node_label(aes(label = node_id), size = 10)
```

[Here is the ggraph plot (since I'm new to SO, I can't embed the image).](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0x2eG.png)

What I want: Edges A->C, D->A, and B->D to be a red gradient, and edges A->B, C->B, and C->D to be a blue gradient. I have a feeling I'm confusing what **geom_edge_arc**'s color aesthetic is doing versus what the **scale_edge_color_*** aesthetic does.

I like that **ggraph** uses the **ggplot** engine and similar syntax, so if at all possible, an answer using **ggraph** would be great. If not, that's okay.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this what you are looking for. There is probably a solution to achieve via a well-specified color gradient. However, after habing a look at the issue a simple solution to get two different "color gradients" is to map `..index..` on the `alpha` aesthetic, while mapping edgegradient on `color`. To get the right colors you could make use `scale_edge_color_identity`:

```
library(tidygraph)
library(ggraph)
library(tibble)

edges_df <- tibble(from = c("A","A","B","C","C","D"),
                   to = c("C","B","D","B","D","A"),
                   edgewidth = c(1,3,3,2,4,1),
                   edgegradient = factor(c("red","blue","red","blue","blue","red"))) 
# I realize edge gradient could be any attribute, not necessarily the names of the desired colors.

nodes_df <- tibble(node_id = c("A","B","C","D"))

my_graph <- tbl_graph(directed = TRUE, nodes = nodes_df, edges = edges_df)

ggraph(my_graph %>%
         activate(edges), layout = "linear", circular = TRUE) +
  geom_edge_arc(aes(width = edgewidth, alpha = stat(..index..), color = edgegradient)) +
  geom_node_label(aes(label = node_id), size = 10) +
  scale_edge_color_identity(guide = "legend")
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for this. I think this will work for my purposes—I was hoping that I could use the viridis color gradient for certain edges, and a gray gradient for the rest. But this will work! Thanks again.